# How to view decrypted results in PostgreSQL dB when using a attribute converter class for encrypting entity fields in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, attributes, converters

I have implemented a custom AttributeConverter class in my Spring Boot application that encrypts and decrypts certain fields of my entities using the AES cipher and a secret key.
Here is my converter class:

```
@Converter
public class DataEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    @Value("${encryption.key}")
    private String encryptionKey;

    private final String encryptionCipher = "AES";

    private Key key;
    private Cipher cipher;

    private Key getKey(){
        if(key == null){
            key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), encryptionCipher);
        }
        return key;
    }

    private Cipher getCipher() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        if(cipher == null){
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionCipher);
        }
        return cipher;
    }


    private void initCipher(int encryptMode) throws GeneralSecurityException{
        getCipher().init(encryptMode, getKey());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(attribute);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getCipher().doFinal(bytes));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        initCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = getCipher().doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData));
        return SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    }
}
```

I use it on the fields I want to encrypt:

```
public Class Task{

@Convert(converter = DataEncryptionConverter.class)
    private String task_title;

@Convert(converter = DataEncryptionConverter.class)
    private String task_description;

}
```

I want to run a select query in my PostgreSQL database to view the result in decrypted form. How can I achieve this?

I tried following but getting errors:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(decode(task_title, 'base64'), 'encryption-key'), 'escape'), 'UTF8') as decrypted_title FROM task;
```

I got this ERROR:  Wrong key or corrupt data

```
SELECT convert(decode(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(decode(task_title, 'base64'), 'encryption-key'), 'escape'), 'UTF8') as decrypted_title FROM task;
```

I got this ERROR:

function convert(bytea, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT convert(decode(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(decode(task_title, 'ba...

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.