# How to use a custom AttributeConverter in a Spring Boot join query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, attributes, converters

I have implemented a custom AttributeConverter class in my Spring Boot application that encrypts and decrypts certain fields of my entities when inserting the data into the database and retrieving the data. The converter works fine when I use it with JPA repository methods. However, when I use it in a join query, I get an error saying "Validation failed for query for method." Here's my converter class:

```
@Converter
public class DataEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    @Value("${encryption.key}")
    private String encryptionKey;

    private final String encryptionCipher = "AES";

    private Key key;
    private Cipher cipher;

    private Key getKey(){
        if(key == null){
            key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), encryptionCipher);
        }
        return key;
    }

    private Cipher getCipher() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        if(cipher == null){
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionCipher);
        }
        return cipher;
    }


    private void initCipher(int encryptMode) throws GeneralSecurityException{
        getCipher().init(encryptMode, getKey());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(attribute);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getCipher().doFinal(bytes));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        initCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = getCipher().doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData));
        return SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    }
}
```

Suppose I have a User class. It works fine if I'm using JPA repository method like

User findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

```
public class User{

// other fields

@Column(name = "first_name")
    @Convert(converter = DataEncryptionConverter.class)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @Convert(converter = DataEncryptionConverter.class)
    private String lastName;
}
```

It doesn't work when I'm using join to retrieve result.

```
public class UserAccount{

// other fields

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
private User fkUserId;

}


@Query("select new EmailFirstLastAccountId(a.email, a.accountId, u.firstName, u.lastName ) from UserAccount a inner join a.fkUserId u where a.orgId=:orgId")
    List<EmailFirstLastAccountId> getEmailAccountIdFirstAndLastNameByOrgId(Long orgId);
```

In this case, the converter is not getting applied. I get the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUtil'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JWTUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.tse.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tse.UserRepository.getEmailAccountIdFirstAndLastNameByOrgId(java.lang.Long)!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JWTUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.tse.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tse.UserRepository.getEmailAccountIdFirstAndLastNameByOrgId(java.lang.Long)!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.tse.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tse.UserRepository.getEmailAccountIdFirstAndLastNameByOrgId(java.lang.Long)!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.tse.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tse.UserRepository.getEmailAccountIdFirstAndLastNameByOrgId(java.lang.Long)!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tse.UserRepository.getEmailAccountIdFirstAndLastNameByOrgId(java.lang.Long)!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.tse.core_application.custom.model.EmailFirstLastAccountId]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, long, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object [select new com.tse.EmailFirstLastAccountId(a.email, a.accountId, u.firstName, u.lastName ) from com.tse.UserAccount a inner join a.fkUserId u where a.orgId=:orgId]

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.tse.EmailFirstLastAccountId]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, long, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object [select new com.tse.EmailFirstLastAccountId(a.email, a.accountId, u.firstName, u.lastName ) from com.tse.UserAccount a inner join a.fkUserId u where a.orgId=:orgId]
```

What could be the issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: THe query validation failed, not sure why you think it has something to do with your attribute converter. Did you use the proper `@Query` and not that it falls back to the name of the method? ALso please provide the **full stacktrace** not just a small snippet.

Comment: The method is part of the existing application (w/o data encryption functionality), and it is working fine. The method throws an exception when I include the convert annotation on the fields, firstName, and lastName of the User Entity. The stack trace is very large but I've added detailed error messages, please check. Thank You!

Comment: THe problem is your converter. It is for an `Object,String` (in the generic types). So in the end you end up with an `Object` and not a `String`. Hence it doesn't find the constructor in your DTO. Change your attribute converter to `String,String` instead of `Object,String` or change your DTO constructor and cast to a `String` in there.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank You so much!
I created a constructor in the projection model for object type and cast the values to String and it worked. 
I have a question though. When we use convert  on a field of any type, this conversion happens automatically right from Object type to type of the field where convert annotation is used. Does this work differently if we define a DTO to get the same values? So now, will I have to always cast it in case of projection models when getting values from the database?

Comment: The problem is your convert is converting from an Object to a String, when executing the query and mapping the result it will see the Object and not the String as a type (due to your converter).

Comment: Got it. I'd really appreciate it if you can also look into a related question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976164/how-to-view-decrypted-results-in-postgresql-db-when-using-a-attribute-converter 

In this question, I'm trying to view the encrypted columns using a select query in Postgres decrypting it with the PGP_SYM_DECRYPT method.

Thank you so much for your help!!